# How to reduce line spacing within footnotes?

Tags: footnotes, line-spacing

[image: footnoes line spaces]

As you can see in the picture (red lines), spaces *within* footnotes is present. 
I've tried to use those two commands:

```
\setlength{\footnotesep}{1pt}   % space between footnotes
\setlength{\skip\footins}{1cm}  % space between body text and footnoes
```

I use the `\setstretch{1.3}` command.

What I want is to clear the spacings inside 
footnoted text, different from the main text.

A [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
%\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
            hyperref=true,
            url=false,
            isbn=false,
            backref=false,
            style=numeric-comp,
            maxcitenames=3,
            maxbibnames=100,
            block=none]{biblatex}\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{manyfoot}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker=true,sorting=none}

% Citation footnotes: use \footnoteA
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}

% Vanilla footnotes: use \footnoteB
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}

% Number of each bibliography entry in brackets
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\makeatletter

\newtoggle{brkText}
% Citation number in brackets
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \iftoggle{brkText}
    {\normalfont[\@thefnmark]\enspace #1}
    {\mkbibsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{brkText}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------
% Mostly verbatim from Joseph Wright
% http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/

\DeclareCiteCommand{\bfcite}[\bracketing]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   %\let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{bfshortcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{bfcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
  {}
  {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
   \global\toggletrue{brkText}%
   \noexpand\footnotetextA[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
     \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}}}}

\newbibmacro*{bfshortcite}{%
  \ifciteseen%
    {}%
    {\iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{article}% checks if the entry type is "article",
                                         % and if true, entry fields and punctuation are 
                                         % printed as specified below; if false, default  
                                         % biblatex citation scheme is used
      {%
        \xappto\cbx@citehook{%
            \global\toggletrue{brkText}%
          \noexpand\footnotetextA[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
            \entrydata{\thefield{entrykey}}{%
            \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}\addperiod\addspace%
            \usebibmacro{title}
            \mkbibemph{\printfield{shortjournal}},\addspace%
            \printfield{year}\addperiod}}}%
      }%
      {\usebibmacro{bfcite}}}}%

\newrobustcmd{\bracketing}[1]{%
  \mkbibbrackets{#1}%
  \cbx@citehook%
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}

\let\brkText=\empty
%---------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatother
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.3}                % space between lines

\addbibresource{example_ref_list.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First citation\bfcite{Torquato2002}.
First citation\bfcite[e.g.][530]{Bernal1959}.
Vanilla footnote\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text 2.}.
First ``multi'' citation\bfcite{Bernal1960,Bernal1959}.


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And the bib entries:

```
@book{Torquato2002,
    author = {Torquato, S.},
    isbn = {978-0387951676},
    publisher = {Springer},
    title = {Random heterogeneous materials: microstructure and macroscopic properties},
    year = {2002}
}
@article{Bernal1962,
    author = {Bernal, J. D.},
    doi = {10.1098/rspa.1964.0147},
    journal = {Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society A: Mathematical, Physical \& Engineering Sciences},
    shortjournal = {Philos. Trans. R. Soc. A},
    pages = {299--322},
    title = {The Bakerian Lecture, 1962. The structure of liquids},
    volume = {280},
    year = {1964}
}
@article{Bernal1960,
    author = {Bernal, J. D. and Mason, J.},
    doi = {10.1038/188910a0},
    journal = {Nature},
    shortjournal = {Nature},
    pages = {910--911},
    publisher = {Nature Publishing Group},
    title = {Packing of spheres: co-ordination of randomly packed spheres},
    volume = {188},
    year = {1960}
}
@article{Bernal1959,
    author = {Bernal, J. D.},
    doi = {10.1038/183141a0},
    journal = {Nature},
    shortjournal = {Nature},
    pages = {141--147},
    title = {A geometrical approach to the structure of liquids},
    volume = {183},
    year = {1959}
}
```

Comment: Isn't that just the `\baselineskip` of footnote text?

Comment: As @MarcelKorpel says, that is spacing *within* footnotes - not between them. The problem seems to be that `\footnotesep` is less than `\baselineskip`.

Comment: Without information about the bib entries "Torquato2002", "Bernal1959", and "Bernal1960", it's not possible to run your program and reproduce the issues related to spacing across footnotes. Please augment your MWE and provide some entries for `example_ref_list.bib`.

Comment: @Mico the example_ref_list.bib has been added.

Comment: It is caused by the use of `\footnoteA` and `\footnoteB` which are not adjusted by `setspace` to use single spacing. If you compare with `\footnote`, you'll see that vanilla footnotes are single spaced and that only the two kinds of fancy footnote are affected by the stretch. I assume that you are also formatting these differently else it would be confusing for readers (to have e.g. two footnotes numbered identically). Can you add that code to your MWE? The bibliography stuff is, I think, a red herring - I can reproduce without it.

Comment: @cfr I've updated the picture. The full code is about my thesis, and putting it here will be not a good idea. Rather I've used another sample about the problem.

Comment: @Mico as cfr pointed, "The bibliography stuff is, I think, a red herring - I can reproduce without it."

Comment: Your MWE should be something ***we*** can compile to reproduce the issue. @Mico's point is that this is not an MWE by those criteria because, without the bib entries, nobody but you can use your code to reproduce the issue. So either create an MWE which reproduces the issue without bib entries or add the bib entries needed to reproduce with them.

Comment: @cfr OK, I'll add the bib entries.

Comment: Unfortunately, your MWE does ***not*** compile even with the bib entries. Undefined control sequences... When I comment that out, it compiles but it does ***not*** reproduce the image posted or anything which illustrates the problem you are asking about. Please ***check your MWE and ensure that you are posting something people can use to reproduce the problem***.

Comment: "Undefined control sequences" like what?

Answer (score 5):

By default, footnotes, like body text, are single-spaced:

[image: default footnotes]

My guess is that your code looks something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
  \kant[1-2]

  This is some text\footnote{Here is a footnote which goes on and on and on and on some more until it takes more than the rest of the line.}. This is some more\footnote{This is another footnote whose name is Harry. Harry is very, very pleased to meet you and ever so excited to be playing a part in this document.}
\end{document}
```

which produces footnotes like this:

[image: poorly spaced]

The problem here is the use of

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
```

without taking any precautions to avoid unwanted spacing screw-ups. The way to do this properly, with the standard classes (`book`, `article`, `report`) is to use `setspace` (or take the precautions yourself):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
  \kant[1-2]

  This is some text\footnote{Here is a footnote which goes on and on and on and on some more until it takes more than the rest of the line.}. This is some more\footnote{This is another footnote whose name is Harry. Harry is very, very pleased to meet you and ever so excited to be playing a part in this document.}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1.5 spacing, single-spaced footnotes]

Since you have not provided a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), it is impossible to do more than guess. So, if this is not the problem, please provide a complete, compilable document demonstrating the issue (and remember to do this when posting future questions).

Comment: I've edited the question. Changing the title to contain "within" and adding a MWE.

Answer (score 0):

as @cfr provided a simple answer, however, my MWE involving sort of advanced code,
i've just added the `\setstretch{1.0}` inside `\@makefntext[1]`:

```
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \setstretch{1.0}
  \iftoggle{brkText}
    {\normalfont[\@thefnmark]\enspace #1}
    {\mkbibsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{brkText}}
```